# setcontext() Valgrind Invalid read of size 8

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm currently facing a very weird problem. I am building a library and linking it to my program. Everything runs fine with no segmentation faults (also checked with gdb) but when I run the program with Valgrind its going crazy with lines saying:

```
==11972== Invalid read of size 8
==11972==    at 0x509509C: setcontext (setcontext.S:73)
==11972==    by 0x509764F: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so)
==11972==  Address 0x541f060 is 128 bytes inside a block of size 936 alloc'd
==11972==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11972==    by 0x402090: environment_get (env.c:99)
==11972==    by 0x401ED6: environment_new (env.c:36)
==11972==    by 0x40124B: thr_new (thr.c:156)
==11972==    by 0x400EBE: main (itest1.c:31)
```

But the program runs fine and `setcontext` has an argument that is malloced properly with no problem. Is there any reason I shall be worried about those lines?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code, ideally a minimal example, that will produce the same error.

Comment: That the program doesn't crash is unfortunate ("silent bugs" they are called). The error happens in your C library, check that the arguments (particularly pointers and addresses of variables) given to library functions are OK size-wise (i.e., not giving a pointer to an char where an int/double is expected). Perhaps something like splint <http://www.splint.org> helps checking such inconsistencies?

Answer (score 4):

Coming to the thread seven years late, but: I fixed this issue by making sure that my stack was at least `SIGSTKSZ`. So, the following code could get around the issue:

```
#include <valgrind/valgrind.h>

//technically, the below doesn't need to be dynamically allocated, but for demonstration:
ucontext_t context = (ucontext_t*) malloc(sizeof(ucontext_t));

getcontext(&context);
void* stack = malloc(SIGSTKSZ);
VALGRIND_STACK_REGISTER(stack, stack + SIGSTKSZ);
context->uc_stack.ss_sp     = stack;
context->uc_stack.ss_size   = SIGSTKSZ;
context->uc_stack.ss_flags  = 0;
sigemptyset(&context->uc_sigmask);
context->uc_link            = &someOtherContextToGoToAfterwards;
makecontext(context, functionForContextToExecute);
```

Then, when cleaning it up, you can do responsible things like:

```
VALGRIND_STACK_DEREGISTER(context->uc_stack.ss_sp);
free(context->uc_stack.ss_sp);
free(context).
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm writing a coroutine library and `VALGRIND_STACK_REGISTER` ended up being the key. The google search that finally brought me here: `valgrind "invalid read of size" "bytes inside a block of size" "alloc'd" -"free'd" -"after a block"`